# Search for an exact match of a string in pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame as follows:

```
data = [
    ['2022-12-04 00:00:00', 5000.00],
    ['2022-12-04 00:00:00', 6799.50],
    ['2022-12-04 00:00:00', 5000.00],
    ['2023-01-10 00:00:00', 5000.00]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Date', 'Float'])


date_input = "2022-12-04 00:00:00"
float_input = "5000.00"
```

What would be the best way to check if there is a string in DF with an exact match of the values 'date' and 'float'.

In such case, I expect the 'Yes' output, since such combination of 'date' and 'float' is contained in the first line of DataFrame.

I tried it like this, but it doesn't help to determine if there is a match of 'float_input' values for a certain 'date_input' date

```
if ((df['Date'] == pd.Timestamp(date_input)).any()) and (df['Float'] == float(float_input).any():
print('YES')
else:
print("No")
```

Comment: The dataframe constructor is not valid, please fix it.

Comment: Are the `Date` values strings or timestamps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good night friend, I performed the process you tried. First, let's break it down:

Step 1:

[image]

Your data set has incorrect values, you have to correct the date to a string before placing it in pd.DataFrame.

[image]

```
data = [
['2022-12-04 00:00:00', 5000.00],
['2022-12-04 00:00:00', 6799.50],
['2022-12-04 00:00:00', 5000.00],
['2023-01-10 00:00:00', 5000.00]]
```

Step 2:

After solving the previous question, we perform the dateframe process:

[image]

Now we can visualize the dateframe, right after that we see that the column that one of the columns we are looking for has a type problem, so we must carry out the conversion

Step 3:

[image]

Using one of the pandas tools, we can convert the type to datetime, you can see that I used the dayfirst parameter, this is optional, but since we don't have hours, minutes and seconds. I didn't choose telos. I followed the documentation which you will find quite interesting.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)
```

Step 4:

Let's go to the consultations, in a simple way, performing a consultation by parts, looking for one at a time. We found your values query

```
SearchDate =  df[df['Date'] == pd.Timestamp("2022-12-04 00:00:00'")]
SearchNumber =  SearchDate[SearchDate['Float'] == 5000.00]
SearchNumber
```

[image]

Another way to search is for the indexes that return True from each query, using the and operator, we manage to return the values of the query

```
searchDate =  df['Date'] == pd.Timestamp("2022-12-04 00:00:00'") 
seachFloat = df['Float'] == 5000.00
query = df[searchDate & seachFloat]
query
```

[image]

Carrying out the table in the previous step in another form of execution

```
query_dataframe = df[(df['Date'] == pd.Timestamp("2022-12-04 00:00:00")) & (df['Float'] == 5000.00)]
query_dataframe
```

[image]

step 5:

This check you put I didn't understand very well. In a simple way, I checked if the variable is empty, I performed the return as in your example

```
if len(query_dataframe):
    print('Yes')
else:
    print('No')
```

[image]

Comment: I would strongly suggest not posting images of code in answers.  There's a long-standing guideline that images should not be used for code in questions, but the same absolutely applies (more so, even) to answers.  I would suggest reading [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

if [date_input,float_input] in df.values:

print('yes')

else:

print('no')